# Outlook email account and attachments - "Download didn't complete. Try again."

Tags: email, exchange, outlook, attachments

On my exchange account - when I receive an email with attachment and want to download it, I get this error every time:

> Download didn't complete. Try again.

Taping again on the attachment has the same effect - same error again.

How can I download the attachment for my outlook account emails?

Comment: Do you know what version of Exchange you're connecting to?

Comment: I am connecting to exchange 2007.

Comment: My phone does the same thing when trying to download an efax pdf sent by email. I have no sync button at this level. To get the sync symbol, I have to go back to the inbox, at which point this email is no longer highlighted. What a horrible bug/glitch for an otherwise decent Windows phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to download the message following these steps:

1. Tap the attachment and let the error message appear.
2. Tap the BACK button
3. Tap the Synchronize botton (the one with arrows)
4. Return to the message - the attachment should be downloaded and available now.

Works with Exchange 2007 and 2010. This should **not** be happening with Exchange **2010 with SP1** installed.

Source: [www.stephenwagner.com](http://www.stephenwagner.com/?p=332)